# Mock an object in a method that is not a parameter in python

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

(i'm a python newbie)

I was looking at: [Mocking out objects and methods](http://packages.python.org/testfixtures/mocking.html)

And I was wondering if i can replace an object in a python method which is not passed as a parameter, lets say my method is like this:

```
def mypymethod(param1)
  myresult = os.path.something
  return myresult
```

and i wish to test mypymethod however i wish **os.path at this case to return "yourmockresult"** when i call it from my test method

anyway i can do this?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Michael Foord's [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) module for the same.

From the documentation:

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> real = ProductionClass()
>>> real.method = Mock(return_value=3)
>>> real.method(3, 4, 5, key='value')
3
>>> real.method.assert_called_with(3, 4, 5, key='value')
```

Comment: so you mean in my case I can do os.path.isdir = False and when i call some method myMethod which would call os.path.isdir then os.path.isdir will return my mock value?

Comment: Thanks!!! I just tried it and its absolutely amazing!!! the dream of every unit tester!!!, is there any framework that can do the same thing in java????